# React - Why this function in onClick doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs

If I write like this, click button works

```
<Menu.Item 
    key={book.uid}
    onClick={() => this.changeColor(book)}     
    >
```

But if I write like this:

```
onClick={this.changeName(book)}
```

the click doesn't work.

So if the function has arguments, I should use "() => xxx(argument); otherwise, I can just use "this.xxx", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because doing `this.changeName(book)` will instantly call the function when rendering. And what your function returns is.. not a function, so when you click, nothing will happen.

And `() => this.changeColor(book)` is an arrow function, it has a similar (but not really) behavior as this syntax :

```
() => { this.changeColor(book) }
```

To avoid this, you could use your first code example or transform your function into a curried one and keep the second syntax in the render :

```
changeName = bookInfo => event => {
    /* Your code here */
}
```

When called once in the render, this function will return another function receiving the event and set the `bookInfo` first.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!